# Scala: ReaderT composition with different contexts and dependencies

Tags: scala, monad-transformers, scala-cats, reader-monad

Example of `s3f1` and `s3f2` functions that return different ReaderT:

```
type FailFast[A] = Either[List[String], A]
trait Service1 { def s1f:Option[Int] = Some(10) }
trait Service2 { def s2f:FailFast[Int] = Right(20) }

import cats.instances.option._

def s3f1: ReaderT[Option, Service1, Int] =
  for {
    r1 <- ReaderT((_: Service1).s1f)
  } yield r1 + 1

import cats.syntax.applicative._
import cats.instances.either._

type ReaderService2FF[A] = ReaderT[FailFast, Service2, A]

def s3f2: ReaderService2FF[Int] =
  for {
    r1 <- ReaderT((_: Service2).s2f)
    r2 <- 2.pure[ReaderService2FF]
  } yield r1 + r2
```

I try to compose these two functions that return readers with different `F[_]` context and dependencies: `ReaderT[Option, Service1, Int]` and `ReaderT[FailFast, Service2, Int]`

I have to combine somehow the `F[_]` context, which means combine `FailFast` with `Option`. I assume, it makes sense to combine it to `FailFast[Option]`:

```
type Env = (Service1, Service2)
type FFOption[A] = FailFast[Option[A]]
type ReaderEnvFF[A] = ReaderT[FFOption, Env, A]
```

How to compose s3f1 and s3f2:

```
def c: ReaderEnvFF[Int] =
  for {
    r1 <- //s3f1
    r2 <- //s3f2
  } yield r1 + r2
```

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Since you try to compose monads `FailFast` and `Option` in `FFOption`, you should use one more monad transformer, so `FFOption[A]` should  be `OptionT[FailFast, A]` rather than just `FailFast[Option[A]]`.

```
import cats.instances.option._
import cats.instances.either._
import cats.syntax.applicative._
import cats.syntax.either._
import cats.syntax.option._

type Env = (Service1, Service2)
type FFOption[A] = OptionT[FailFast, A]
type ReaderEnvFF[A] = ReaderT[FFOption, Env, A]

def c: ReaderEnvFF[Int] =
  for {
    r1 <- ReaderT[FFOption, Env, Int](p => OptionT(Either.right(s3f1.run(p._1))))     
    r2 <- ReaderT[FFOption, Env, Int](p => OptionT(s3f2.run(p._2).map(_.some)))                          
  } yield r1 + r2
```

This can be rewritten with with `local` and `mapF`:

```
def c: ReaderEnvFF[Int] =
  for {
    r1 <- s3f1.local[Env](_._1).mapF[FFOption, Int](opt => OptionT(opt.asRight))
    r2 <- s3f2.local[Env](_._2).mapF[FFOption, Int](ff => OptionT(ff.map(_.some)))                      
  } yield r1 + r2
```